# Why Visual Studio stops debugging while javascript pac file is enabled on developing machine?

Tags: javascript, networking, visual-studio-2012

I'm suffering from this problem since last week, I'm on a network where Javascript Pac file is enabled while i'm debugging by my Visual Studio project it gets an error.

[image]